# How do I print out each value for a dictionary item in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of 'id' and their vaules. I am trying to loop through the list and print out the values of each 'id'. It has to be done in one line though. I am struggling to come up with the solution though. The closest I have gotten is below:

```
ls = [
{'id':'1'},{'id':'2'},{'id':'3'},{'id':'4'},{'id':'5'},
{'id':'6'},{'id':'7'},{'id':'8'},{'id':'9'},{'id':'10'},
{'id':'11'},{'id':'12'},{'id':'13'},{'id':'14'},{'id':'15'},
{'id':'16'},{'id':'17'},{'id':'18'},{'id':'19'},{'id':'20'},
{'id':'21'},{'id':'22'},{'id':'23'},{'id':'24'},{'id':'25'}
]

print([(ls[num]['id']) for num in range(25)])
```

This gives me the values for each 'id' in the list which is great! But, it returns them all in a list. I need them all on separate lines. Like so:

```
'1'
'2'
'3'
'4'
'5'
```

Any ideas how I can go about this? It has to be done with a one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want a one liner, you can make use of unpacking and the `sep` argument of `print`:

```
print(*[(ls[num]['id']) for num in range(25)], sep="\n")
```

`*` unpacks the elements into the arguments of `print`, then `sep` tells `print` to add a newline between each printed argument.

I think this would be neater by making use of a full `for` loop though, with separate `print`s:

```
for elem in [(ls[num]['id']) for num in range(25)]:
    print(elem)
```

I'd personally only use that one-liner for quick debugging.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you! Yeah, I was able to do it in a for loop but I really was trying to figure out how to do it in one line just in case it ever came up! Thank you!